# How can I get Skaffold to list which files have changed when it detects a change?

Tags: skaffold

After running `skaffold dev` skaffold enters a continuous rebuilding loop. On the assumption that the rebuild is being triggered by a file change I would like to figure out which file is being changed.

I have seen other people reference `[INFO]` output with changed filenames, but have no such output. Immediately after deployed services come up they are shut down and I see

`Generating tags ...` and the build starts again.

Leading me to believe that the file watcher has been triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `skaffold dev -vinfo`: by default, Skaffold only shows log messages of level WARN and higher.